# Cant append <span> inside <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to append this new element

```
<a data-toggle="tab"> <span class = "hyperspan"> </span> </a>
```

but, `<span class="hyperspan"></span>` does not appear on the console after the append. it makes me not able to select element through button, must click text (element ).

Try Fill in the **input form** and **submit** in [My JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4fukuma/qb8b4hcj/31/) and click the *second button*.

Button will not work if  is *text* not clicked.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```js
$('.submitButton').click(function () {
  var add = '<li>' +
      '<div class="zf-folder">' +
        '<div id="tabFolder3" class="_tabFolder _itemPosition" style="height: 40px;border-bottom:1px groove; user-select: none;">' +
          '<div class="_sideFolder"></div>' +
          '<div class="_iconText" style="width: 215px">' +
            '<div class="ellipsis">' +
              '<div class="_iconFolder">' +
                '<div class="_icon-col">' +
                '</div>' +
              '</div>' +
              
              '<a data-toggle="tab"><span class="hyperspan"></span></a>' +
            
            '</div>' +
          '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
    '</li>';
    
    if( document.getElementById("addNew").value === '' ){
            alert("WRITE SOMETHING");
        } else {
          $('.nav').append(add)
      var inputan = document.getElementById("addNew").value;
            $('li:last').find('a').text(inputan);
            document.getElementById("newFoldr").value = "";
            }
});
```

```css
._sideFolder {
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 5px
}

.zf-folder:active ._sideFolder,
li.active .zf-folder ._sideFolder {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 5px
}

.zf-folder a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

._tabFolder {
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

._tabFolder:hover {
  background-color: grey
}

._tabFolder:active,
li.active ._tabFolder {
  background-color: rgba(29, 33, 41, 1)
}

._itemPosition {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex
}

._iconText:hover ._1i5y,
.uiPopover.selected ._1i5y {
  display: block
}

._iconText {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 13px;
}

._iconFolder,
._1i5x,
._1i5w {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle
}

._5bme ._iconFolder {
  background-image: url(/rsrc.php/v3/yE/r/miCSJRxMvJi.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto;
  background-position: -412px -21px
}

.hyperspan {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<input type="text" id="addNew" placeholder="Write something">
<input type="button" class="submitButton" id="submitButton" value="Create" style="width:142px;margin-left: 5px;">

<ul class="nav">

  <li class="active">
    <div class="zf-folder">
      <div id="tabFolder" class="_tabFolder _itemPosition" style="height: 40px;border-bottom:1px groove; user-select: none;">
        <div class="_sideFolder"></div>
        <div class="_iconText" style="width: 215px">
          <div class="ellipsis">
            <div class="_iconFolder">
              <div class="_icon-col">
              </div>
            </div>
            
            <a href="#mainFolder" aria-controls="mainFolder" data-toggle="tab">Main Folder<span class="hyperspan"></span></a>
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="zf-folder">
      <div id="tabFolder2" class="_tabFolder _itemPosition" style="height: 40px;border-bottom:1px groove; user-select: none;">
        <div class="_sideFolder"></div>
        <div class="_iconText" style="width: 215px">
          <div class="ellipsis">
            <div class="_iconFolder">
              <div class="_icon-col">
              </div>
            </div>

            <a href="#secondFolder" aria-controls="secondFolder" data-toggle="tab">Second Folder<span class="hyperspan"></span></a>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Can you try `html` instead of `text` in your code `$('li:last').find('a').text(inputan);`? Also it would be nice if you could provide a minimal working example, this is really too much code.

Comment: `</ span>` -> `</span>`

Comment: ok wait,  I'll make the code more simple.

Comment: [UPDATED JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4fukuma/qb8b4hcj/27/) & SNIPPET

Comment: If you already create element and submit, click the button, dont click text.

Comment: `<span></span>` will disappear after creating new element.

Comment: In your example, you never add your "add" variable

Comment: Am I blind or you create `var add` and never use it?

Comment: OMG, sorry, i have no slept last nigh. wait

Comment: UPDATED [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4fukuma/qb8b4hcj/31/)

Comment: the new element is not visible in the snippet, enclosed error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `html()`instead of `text()` if you want span as below.

```
$('li:last').find('a').html(inputan+'<span class="hyperspan"></span>');
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Why is this so easy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're overwriting the contents of the `a` element when you do:

```
$('li:last').find('a').text(inputan);
```

You could instead, put the text before the `span` element, like this:

```
$('li:last').find('span').before(inputan);
```

```js
$('.submitButton').click(function () {
  var add = '<li>' +
      '<div class="zf-folder">' +
        '<div id="tabFolder3" class="_tabFolder _itemPosition" style="height: 40px;border-bottom:1px groove; user-select: none;">' +
          '<div class="_sideFolder"></div>' +
          '<div class="_iconText" style="width: 215px">' +
            '<div class="ellipsis">' +
              '<div class="_iconFolder">' +
                '<div class="_icon-col">' +
                '</div>' +
              '</div>' +
              
              '<a data-toggle="tab"><span class="hyperspan"></span></a>' +
            
            '</div>' +
          '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
    '</li>';
    
    if( document.getElementById("addNew").value === '' ){
            alert("WRITE SOMETHING");
        } else {
          $('.nav').append(add)
      var inputan = document.getElementById("addNew").value;
            $('li:last').find('span').before(inputan);
            document.getElementById("newFoldr").value = "";
            }
});
```

```css
._sideFolder {
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 5px
}

.zf-folder:active ._sideFolder,
li.active .zf-folder ._sideFolder {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 5px
}

.zf-folder a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

._tabFolder {
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

._tabFolder:hover {
  background-color: grey
}

._tabFolder:active,
li.active ._tabFolder {
  background-color: rgba(29, 33, 41, 1)
}

._itemPosition {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex
}

._iconText:hover ._1i5y,
.uiPopover.selected ._1i5y {
  display: block
}

._iconText {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 13px;
}

._iconFolder,
._1i5x,
._1i5w {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle
}

._5bme ._iconFolder {
  background-image: url(/rsrc.php/v3/yE/r/miCSJRxMvJi.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto;
  background-position: -412px -21px
}

.hyperspan {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="addNew" placeholder="Write something">
<input type="button" class="submitButton" id="submitButton" value="Create" style="width:142px;margin-left: 5px;">

<ul class="nav">

  <li class="active">
    <div class="zf-folder">
      <div id="tabFolder" class="_tabFolder _itemPosition" style="height: 40px;border-bottom:1px groove; user-select: none;">
        <div class="_sideFolder"></div>
        <div class="_iconText" style="width: 215px">
          <div class="ellipsis">
            <div class="_iconFolder">
              <div class="_icon-col">
              </div>
            </div>
            
            <a href="#mainFolder" aria-controls="mainFolder" data-toggle="tab">Main Folder<span class="hyperspan"></span></a>
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="zf-folder">
      <div id="tabFolder2" class="_tabFolder _itemPosition" style="height: 40px;border-bottom:1px groove; user-select: none;">
        <div class="_sideFolder"></div>
        <div class="_iconText" style="width: 215px">
          <div class="ellipsis">
            <div class="_iconFolder">
              <div class="_icon-col">
              </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#secondFolder" aria-controls="secondFolder" data-toggle="tab">Second Folder<span class="hyperspan"></span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Here you have it on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qb8b4hcj/35/